# Link doesnt work in xpath Selenium Webdriver (Ajax-container)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
class ClickAndSendKeys():

    def test(self):
        # Driverlocation
        driverLocation = "C:/Users/Dennis.Pieruschka/Documents/chromedriver.exe"
        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driverLocation
        # Instantiate Chrome Browser Command
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverLocation)
        driver.maximize_window()
        url = "http://www.visservanbaars.nl/vacatures"
        driver.get(url)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ajax-container']//form//div//input").click()
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ajax-container']//form//div//input").send_keys("Bi Consultant")
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ajax-container']//form//div/span/button").click()

ff = ClickAndSendKeys()
ff.test()
```

When I run this code, Selenium doesn't go to the next page

xpath is correct but when it clicks it closes the window directly.
Does anyone know how to work with it?

Comment: Which Link ois not clickable

Comment: I guess     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ajax-container']//form//div//input").click()
this creates issue

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the python . Please convert it to JAVA

Please check this code it works:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.visservanbaars.nl/vacatures");
WebElement elem=    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ajax-container']//form//div//input"));
elem.sendKeys("World");
elem.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); someone convert into python code :D

Comment: send_keys(Keys.RETURN) or send_keys(Keys.ENTER)